# Send a broadcast e-mail in Aweber using .NET API

Tags: c#, rest, email, broadcast, aweber

I want to send a broadcast email using Aweber .NET API. I can authenticate and I can retrieve a list of subscribers.

When I create a broadcast, it creates succesfully (the request doesn't fail) and I get back a JSON containing the info about the broadcast that I've just created. However, in the aweber account, I go to broadcasts and I don't see anything about the broadcast I've just created using the API! It is not sent, or scheduled or draft. It simply doesn't exist.

This is the code that I use for creating the broadcast:

```
string endpoint = string.Format("https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/{0}/lists/{1}/broadcasts", account_id, list_id);

Request request = new Request
{
      oauth_consumer_key = consumerKey,
      oauth_consumer_secret = consumerSecret, 
      oauth_token = token,
      oauth_token_secret = api.OAuthTokenSecret
};

SortedList<string, string> parameters = new SortedList<string, string>();

parameters.Add("click_tracking_enabled", "True");
parameters.Add("is_archived", "True");
parameters.Add("notify_on_send", "True");
parameters.Add("body_text", "xxxxx");
parameters.Add("subject", "yyyyyy");

request.Build(parameters, endpoint);
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string str = string.Empty;

str = client.UploadString(endpoint, request.Parameters);
```

After execution, the str string has the following content:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the "sent" property is null, so basically it is not sent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The broadcast needs to be scheduled. This is the code:

```
Broadcast broadcast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Broadcast>(str);

endpoint = endpoint + string.Format("/{0}/schedule", broadcast.broadcast_id);

Request new_request = new Request()
{
        oauth_consumer_key = consumerKey,
        oauth_consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
        oauth_token = token,
        oauth_token_secret = api.OAuthTokenSecret
};

SortedList<string, string> new_parameters = new SortedList<string, string>();

new_parameters.Add("scheduled_for", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));

new_request.Build(new_parameters, endpoint);

WebClient new_client = new WebClient();

new_client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

str = new_client.UploadString(endpoint, new_request.Parameters);
```